# How to reschedule a task in Spring Batch with new cron expression

Tags: spring-scheduled

I am invoking a task with cron expression got from UI in the controller.

```
taskScheduler.schedule(scheduledTask, new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
```

And the task is created with the given cron expression. But when I again hit the controller with different cron expression, it is creating a new task without stopping the existing task.

I wanted either to stop the old task and start the task with new cron expression  or reschedule the existing task with new cron expression

Comment: I.m still not able to figure this out